# JPGs created with Imagemagick won't display on TV

Tags: pdf, tv, gimp, imagemagick, jpeg

I am trying to convert a free ebook from PNG to JPG, so I can read it on my Sony Bravia KDL-40R470.

This is how I converted the PNG file:

```
convert -density 117 -quality 80 progit.pdf progit.jpg
```

Unfortunately, my TV refuses to display [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlBCF.jpg). Changing density and quality makes no difference.

However, when I manually capture a screenshot in a PDF viewer, crop that screenshot in GIMP and export it to JPG with the same quality of 80, [the resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkc89.jpg) displays just fine on my TV.

However, manually converting hundreds of pages is simply not an option for me :)

Can anybody spot potential problems in the first JPG file that would make a TV refuse to display it? Which Imagemagick options would be recommended to mitigate these problems?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using Ghostscript instead of Imagemagick:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=90 -r117 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -tGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile="progit-%03d.jpg" "progit.pdf"
```

The resulting images consume a lot less memory now, and the image quality is awesome.

Comment: Within the GIMP community,  we have found that many devices won't display progressive JPEG files (some controller types must have decided that this saves them 5  cent per device). I'd check if you can control that with an ImageMagick option.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher In the meantime, I solved the problem again, by buying a Kindle ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your first image is CMYK which is OK from a jpeg specification standpoint, but often not supported. Try adding `-colorspace RGB`

[other options manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace)